# TableView reload from Segue not working in Swift 3

Tags: swift, tableview, reloaddata

In Swift v3, my TableView is not reloading upon segue.  I am pretty sure that this code was working in 2.0.

```
@IBAction func unwindToLevelListView(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue)
{
    print("RELOADING VIEW")
    TableView.reloadData()
}
```

RELOADING VIEW prints, but the TableView does not reload.  I've also tried putting this code in ViewDidLoad and ViewDidAppear, but neither of those worked.

P.S. A point of note, the rows also don't reload upon display (i.e. scroll down and then back up).

Assistance is greatly appreciated.

Code Follows:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    TableView.reloadData()
}

// Create Table
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LevelSelected", for: indexPath) as! LevelListCell

    // Set labels
    cell.levelNameLabel.text = "LEVEL " + String(puzzleLevels[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row])
    let unlocked: Bool = puzzleUnlocked[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]

    if(challengeSelected == 1 && (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row == 0 && puzzleUnlocked[1] == false)
    {
        cell.levelStatusLabel.text = "Not Solved"
    }
    else if(unlocked == true)
    {
        cell.levelStatusLabel.text = "Solved"
    }
    else
    {
        cell.levelStatusLabel.text = "Not Solved"
    }

    // Set color
    cell.levelNameLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    cell.levelStatusLabel.textColor = UIColor.white

    if unlocked == false
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        // Uncomment to disable interaction
        // cell.userInteractionEnabled = false // Comment Out to Remove Lock
    }
    else if unlocked == true
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 64, blue: 128, alpha: 0.0)
        cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return puzzleLevels.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    levelSelected = (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "LevelSelected", sender: levelSelected);
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
    if (segue.identifier == "LevelSelected")
    {
        if let nextViewController = (segue.destination as? GameViewController)
        {
            nextViewController.selectedLevel = levelSelected
            nextViewController.selectedChallenge = challengeSelected
        }
        print("List View Level Selected:\(levelSelected)")
    }
}

@IBAction func unwindToLevelListView(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue)
{
    print("RELOADING VIEW")
    TableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: did you set an outlet to the tableview/use a tableviewcontroller? reloadData() reloads those rows, that are visible, during segue, there is no row visible yet. that's why it's not called. try to set self.tableView.reload() into "viewDidApprear" - this HAS TO work. if it's not working, there is some futher issue with your code. in that case please provide the code to populate your tableView

Comment: Thank you.  I added it in viewDidAppear and unfortunately it's still not displaying.  Providing the code for the tableView.  All of the other functionality outside of the reload is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the responses.  I was able to figure out what is going on.  The most important thing when doing the segue is to ensure that values are re-established.

```
@IBAction func unwindToLevelListView(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue)
{
    print("RELOADING VIEW")
    let getLevels = Level(challengeNumber: challengeSelected, gameSelected: gameSelected)
    puzzleLevels = getLevels.puzzleLevels
    puzzleUnlocked = getLevels.unlocked
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:"reloadData", name:
NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "reloadTableView"), object: nil)

func reloadData(){
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
            print("Work SO !!")
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
}

NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "reloadTableView"), object: nil)
```

Comment: I'll try this tonight.  Thank you.  Shouldn't it not need a delay timer?

Comment: that is what i use in my tableVIew.. maybe you can remove the delay timer. You need get in viewDidLoad(),

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working.  I've loaded it everywhere I can think of and also used the delays.  Do you think it could have anything to do with the realm loads?

Comment: Thank you.  It was that the variables were not being reset upon segue.  The reload works from the segue, but the variables have to be reset in order for the tableView to show the updated changes.  You are correct, your code works so long as the variables are set as well.